# Springboot cloud stream kafka binder, Not to log the whole payload (failedMessage=GenericMessage)

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

In the case of consumer failure after retries, I see the whole payload gets logged. 
`failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=`
Is there an easy way to mask it or hide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your own `errorChannel` bean. It indeed could be the same `PublishSubscribeChannel` and declare your own `LoggingHandler` as a subscriber to that channel. Its:

```
/**
 * Set a SpEL expression string to use.
 * @param expressionString the SpEL expression string to use.
 * @since 4.3
 * @see #setLogExpression(Expression)
 */
public void setLogExpressionString(String expressionString) {
```

can be used to declare whatever you could log or want within an incoming `Message` context.